# Naming multiple sheet in excel report generate by rdlc for asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, rdlc

i'm trying to create an Excel report using RDLC for ASP .NET. I created a report with multiple dynamic sheets, one for every group of my data using Parent Group Row. I would like to name my sheet with the value of the field that i used to group my data but the report isn't linked with my group and the name of the sheet is static and is the first value of the field. Can you help me? 
Thanks to all

In the first image there is the Row Parent Group that i use to divided my data in different sheets

Comment: Please add an example that shows us your problem

Comment: When i try to add the filed for naming the sheet, in the tablix properties, it shows error "Report item not linked to a dataset." But in the properties there  is already the Dataset, what can i try to do?